# How do I prevent a position: relative item from showing up on top of a position: fixed item?

Tags: css, css-position

I have an issue regarding style my blog. I want to make the header bar

```
position:fixed
```

The header bar looks like this:

```
.blurbheader {
    position:fixed;
    padding:4px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    color:#fff;
    background:#cc0000;
    font: 12px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    line-height:1.3em;
}

.blurbheader a {color: #fff;}

/* creates the triangle */
.blurbheader:after {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-40px;
    left:210px;
    border:20px solid transparent;
    border-top-color:#cc0000;

    /* reduce the damage in FF3.0 */
    display:block; width:0;
}
```

But as soon and I do that, 2 navigation bars I made, which are shown as

```
.blurb {
    position:relative;
    padding:10px;
    margin:20px 0 0.5em;
    color:#fff;
    background:#000;
    font: 11px Georgia, Geneva, "Times New Roman", times;
    line-height:1.3em;
}

.blurb a {color: #fff;}

/* creates the triangle */
.blurb:after {
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    top:-30px; left:20px;
    border:15px solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color:#000;

    /* reduce the damage in FF3.0 */
    display:block; width:0;
}
```

When try to make the headerbar (blurbheader) fixed, when I scroll, it looks like this:

[image]

The box on the right hand side is the navigation bar, which won't scroll *under* the header bar. What do I do?

Comment: have you tried to give the header a higher z-index like `.blurbheader { z-index: 1000; }`

Comment: It works! Thank you so much! I tried lower number z-index. I'm pretty new to the whole "fixed" content thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a z-index issue.

try adding the following to your `.blurbheader`

```
 z-index:1;
```

and whatever is holding the rest of the page, like the wrapper, add a

```
z-index:0;
```

that should fix the problem

Comment: Keep in mind that in most browsers that z-index is absolute to the page, however in IE, it is relative to the parent element, so this will not work for IE.